# How to create an attribute for "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'is_string_like'"?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Since new version of matplotlib.cbook does not have `is_string_like`, but `networkx` needs it. I think it should be possible to fix by creating my own `matplotlib.cbook.is_string_like`. How to create an `matplotlib` attribute and import it?

Comment: copy that function and patch it as that attribute `class_name.attribute_name = <that_func>`

Comment: What are you expecting `matplotlib.cbook.is_string_like` to do? What did it do in the old version? What does the documentation say about why it's gone?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it checks an object whether it is string. According to API, "many unused or near-unused `matplotlib.cbook` functions and classes have been deprecated" including `is_string_like` [link](https://matplotlib.org/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.0.0.html?). However, `networkx` still uses it to build a graph.

Comment: @Aditya may you explain a bit more?: if `matplotlib.cbook.is_string_like(obj)`
`Return True` if `obj` looks like a string. Can I add `matplotlib.cbook.is_string_like = lambda obj: isinstance(obj, str)` into my code?